# How to use column of mPDF on Yii2?

Tags: php, pdf, yii, yii2, mpdf

I am using mPDF to convert my reports to PDF. I need two columns for my table but I am generating this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVhCu.png)

I already used different ways to add columns

`<columns column-count="2" vAlign="J" column-gap="5" />`
I also tried adding this,
`'SetColumns' => [2, 'J', 3],`

but everything didn't work and gives the same error. This is my code on my controller.

```
        set_time_limit(300);
        ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
        $model = new Reports();
        $auditrecord = new Auditrecord();
        $regionlist = Tblregion::find()->all();
        $questionnairep = Reports::getquestionnaire($reportyear, 3);
        $questionnairehuc = Reports::getquestionnaire($reportyear, 2);
        $questionnairecm = Reports::getquestionnaire($reportyear, 1);
         $htmlContent = $this->renderPartial('resultscore', [
            'model' => $model, 
            'reportyear' => $reportyear,
            'questionnairep' => $questionnairep,
            'questionnairehuc' => $questionnairehuc,
            'questionnairecm' => $questionnairecm,
            'regionlist' => $regionlist,  
            'auditrecord' => $auditrecord,          
               
        ]);

        $fname = Yii::$app->user->identity->userinfo->FIRST_M;
        $lname = Yii::$app->user->identity->userinfo->LAST_M;
        $now = date('Y-m-d h:i:s A');
        
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT ,
            
            'marginTop' => 40,
            'cssInline' => '.left{margin-right: 100px;}',
            'methods' => [ 
                //'SetHeader'=>[$header], 
                //'SetColumns' => [2, 'J', 3],   
                'SetFooter'=>['<p class="text-left">' . $now .'</p> Page {PAGENO}'],
            ],
            ]);
        $mpdf = $pdf->api;
        //$mpdf->SetColumns(2, 'J', 3);
        $mpdf->useSubstitutions = false; 
       // $mpdf->simpleTables = true;
        // $mpdf->keepColumns = true;
        // $mpdf->SetColumns(3);
        
        $mpdf->SetFooter('<p class="text-left">' . $now .'</p> Page {PAGENO} ');

        $pdf->content = $htmlContent;
        return $pdf->render();
```

Comment: Try to check the parametets of renderpartial before using them.

Comment: I don't think there's something wrong with how I use renderPartial or the parameters I used. It's also what the mPdf documentation stated, to use renderPartial. Or please explain to me what I didnt know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that using `setColumn` would work on using mPDF the same manner it was used on the documentation of [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/getting-started/creating-your-first-file.html)

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
        'margin_top' => 36,
        'margin_bottom' => 20,
        'margin_left' => 10,
        'margin_right' => 10,
        'options' => ['filename' => 'Dossier de travail '],
        'cssInline' => '.left{margin-right: 100px;}',
        'methods' => [ 
            'SetHeader'=>[$header], 
           ],
        ]);
    
    $mpdf->SetColumns(2, 'J', 3);
    $mpdf->SetHeader($header);
    $mpdf->SetFooter('
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><b><small>' . $now .'</small></b></td>
                <td align="right"><b><small>Page {PAGENO}</small></b></td>
            </tr>
        </table>');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlContent);
    
    $mpdf->Output();
```